# Angle in Biot-Savart formal in conductor loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am referring to this problem in Griffiths:

[image]

[image]

My question: where does cos(theta) come from? r and dl are perpendicular to each other so with the formal from Biot-Savart, dlxr (vectors) = dl and nothing more. I see the explanation in parentheses but it still doesn't make sence.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: It is because you need the projection of $dB$ onto the $z$ axis.

Comment: $d\vec{l}\times\vec{r}$ is a vector, which needs to be split into components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at a single $dB$. Now compare it to a $dB$ contributed by an element of current on the *opposite* side of the ring. You will see their components that lie on the xy plane point opposite directions and thus cancel each other leaving you with just the $z$ component of each $dB$. Going around the full circle does this to each "$dB$" contributed by a $dl$ length of current. $\cos{\theta}$ will give you the adjacent side of the $dB$ right triangle in the diagram which points along the z axis - this is the $z$ component of $dB$. $\theta$ is the same for all points along the ring so $\cos{\theta}$ is a constant that can be moved outside the integral.

Also, $\vec{dl} \times \vec{r} \neq \vec{dl}$. It equals $dl$ multiplied by $r$ (where the sine of the angle between $dl$ and $r$ is 90 degrees and so sine of 90 degrees is just $1$). $r$ is the same for all points on the ring (all $dl$'s are the same distance away from the point in question) so $r$ can be taken outside the integral and you are left with just integrating $dl$ around the circle which is just the circumference of the circle.